# iBus on busy system

Tags: ibus

When the system is quite busy I see that iBus switches layout with noticeable delay. I switch the layout, begin typing (in GEdit, for instance) and I have the beginning of the word in previous locale and the ending in newly switched locale. Maybe this is subjective but in Qt apps this is more noticeable (Skype, GoldenDict).

Is it possible to fix or iBus input method is broken by design?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I expect that as the X will wait for `ibus-daemon` reply, which adds another delay layer to input.

- May be the best is to `renice` it for some periods or use `nice` permanently.
- Or change the delay `400` declared in `/etc/dconf/db/ibus.d/00-upstream-settings`

  **Global Settings:**

  1. Create new file: `/etc/dconf/db/ibus.d/01-my-settings` contains:

     ```
     [desktop/ibus/general]
     switcher-delay-time=150
     ```
  2. ```
     dconf update
     ```

  **Single User settings:**

  ```
  dconf write /desktop/ibus/general/switcher-delay-time 150
  ```

  Use `dconf-editor` if you are looking for GUI tool.

Comment: The `/etc/dconf/db/ibus.d/00-upstream-settings` says also to do `dconf update` in it's comments. Thank you for the tip. Will check that!

Comment: @igorp1024, right I missed that. Updated the answer.